# What happens to the associaton bonus if an user is deleted and then recreate on a site?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts, association-bonus

This question came to mind while reading a comment on another question about loosing privileges dues to bounties.

Suppose an user has enough rep on a site to get the association bonus on their other accounts. They create an account on another site and get the free +100 rep points...

**They then proceed to give out said points in a bounty and then delete the account.**

This should be possible, since it was documented that the association point rewards can indeed be spent on a bounty. Also, bounties are "immune" to the user deletion effect, so they won't be "detracted" when the user is removed.
This means that the bounty will survive the user deletion.

This in turn brings another question: what happens now if the user recreates a new account on the same site? Is the association bonus given out again?

Obviously, you can all see where this is going....

Could one technically game the system by creating an user, moving the rep to another sock and then "rerolling" the same user again to get a free association bonus for each reroll? And as a bonus question... should we fix this (I guess a similar behavior would be very noticeable, so  I don't even know if it would be worth fixing this "exploit")

Comment: Ah you beat me to it Glorfindel. I knew this was asked before.

Comment: I wonder if Nicael (ab)used this route for science. I'm pretty sure it was discussed in the Tavern.

Comment: Oh, nice, already mentioned. I did some basic search, and yet I didn't think of just searching for the obvious word "abuse".... Forgive me, please ^_^'